# How to import date value from Excel into SQL Server containing zero date?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

When I try to import date values from Excel into SQL Server and the values contain zero date like this `2013-01-00`, these are saved in the database as null value. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What you want to save in these type of dates? `

Comment: i have file excel contain column with name ( date ) with these values :-
3/15/2001
2013-01-00
11/8/2001
1/29/1999
5/26/2001
12/4/2001
7/18/2001
3/10/2001
7/28/2001
4/21/2001
3/29/2001
7/8/2001
7/19/2000
1/1/2001
12/4/2000
9/25/2001
9/16/2001
5/23/2001
2/15/2001
12/25/2001
5/3/2001
9/18/2001
9/24/2000

and i want to export this column to sql server 2008 using import/export wizard , when i finish , this date ( 2013-01-00 ) saved as null and this is the problem . so how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Its not possible to store this date ' 2013-01-00' into sql. You need to convert it into some actual date.

Comment: That value is not a valid date[time] value. Why day part is `0` ?

Comment: i don't have a permission to change this date ' 2013-01-00' so i try to find way to save this date in the database

Comment: This is not even a valid date, of course you won't be able to save it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state the method/environment you are using for importing, so general suggestions are:

- Do a specific replacement:

  If (ImportValue = '2013-01-00') Then Import('1/1/1970') Else Import(ImportValue)
- Do an IsDate test and replacement:

  If IsDate(ImportValue) Then Import(ImportValue) Else Import('1/1/1970')
- After import, use SQL to replace all null date values, and change to a real date

Let us know what environment you are using for better example.

Comment: my environment ( sql server 2008 ) and i using ( sql server import and export wizard )

can you tell me how can i use the if Condition (If (ImportValue = '2013-01-00') Then Import('1/1/1970') Else Import(ImportValue) ) 

i mean where i can put this condition in the sql or in the excel ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the wizard, you will not get a chance to create an "If ... Then ..." statement, but it is easy to import the data then change the NULL values using the SQL Server Management Studio (SQL-SMS) tools.

To use the Wizard to import Excel data into SQL Server:

```
Launch the Import and Export Data (32-bit), click Next
Specify Excel Data Source and workbook name,
  Hopefully, the existing spreadsheet has column names in the first row
    if so then check "First row has column names"
  click Next
Choose the Destination SQL Server, Authentication, and Database, click Next
Click "Copy data from one or more tables or views", click Next
Check-mark the Sheet within the workbook you want to import from
  If you want a specific table name, edit the "Destination" column
    For this example, I am importing to table "TestExcelImport"
  Make sure the desired Source Sheet stays hi-lighted, click the "Edit Mappings" button,
  depending on if the spreadsheet had column names in the first row
    you may see those column names in the "Source" column
    you can change the "Destination" column names if you prefer a different field name
  you can click the "Preview..." button to see approximately what your imported data will look like
  click Next
Check-mark "Run immediately", click Next
Review the summary
  you should see something like "Copy rows from 'Sheet1$' to [TestExcelImport]"
  click Finish
The wizard will execute, and show you details of the process
  click Close
```

To update the rows where the date field is NULL:

```
Open SQL-SMS, connect to the SQL Server you imported to
Browse to the database, then expand "Tables"
  Tip: if you already had SQL-SMS open, you may need to right-click "Tables" and select "Refresh"
Right-click the table you imported to, then click "Edit top 1000 rows"
  In my example above, this would be table "TestExcelImport"
  You should see your table with it's data (including some NULL date values)
We want to filter for records that have NULL date values,
  From the menu, choose: Query Designer > Pane > Criteria
  Tip: you can optionally choose to see the SQL pane also, handy for studying SQL syntax
  In the upper "Criteria" pane, find the date row, then over in the "Filter" column type: null
  (it will change to "IS NULL" automatically)
  click the red exclamation mark button in the toolbar, labeled "Execute SQL"
  you will see in the lower pane, only the records that have NULL for date
Change the Query Type to update records
  From the menu, choose: Query Designer > Change Type > Update
  You will now in the upper "Criteria" pane an new column named "New Value"
  In the date value row, in the "New Value" column, specify the date you want to replace NULL
    Example: type "1/1/1980" in the "New Value" column if you want that date to replace all NULL date values
  Note: be SURE the "IS NULL" is still in the "Filter" column
  click the red exclamation mark button in the toolbar to run the UPDATE query.
Close then re-open this table to see NULL date values replaced with 1/1/1980
  Optionally: do a "Change Type" back to "Select", and remove the "IS NULL" filter
```

Hope this helps!!
(68m)